# Step Down Voltage Converter with Commutator motor

Tags: transformer, step-down

I got a leaf blower which I bought from Japan and intend to use it in Thailand 
(220V => 100V). I found a step-down converter which can not be used on electronic stuffs.
(the blower runs on motor only so I suppose it would be fine)

The blower specs are as follows

```
Motor type : some kind of commutator motor
Voltage    : single-phase 100 V
Current    : 12 A
Power      : 1,100 W
```

the tranformer specs are

```
220-240VAC to 100VAC, 2.5 A Max., 50/60Hz,26-1875W
```

Here, I found the max current very strange.

Another device

```
220V±10% to 110V±10%, 10A Max. 50/60Hz, 2000W max
```

The problem is the current my blower need is 12A which is more than the max current specified by both devices.

- Should there be any problem?
- After all shouldn't the max current be calculated by max wattage divied by voltage?
- Would it be okay to use any of these transformer?

Comment: You could try it, maybe the motor only draws 12A max but on regular use it draws less. If the motor draws more than 10A you may expect a voltage drop from the transformer in order to keep it at 10A (in this case the motor rotates a bit slower but still usable) or if nothing happens you might damage the transformer due to the high current. Certainly use the 10A one instead of the 2.5A to give it a try.

Comment: Will try the 10A one then. Let's see what will happen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the 2000W unit will be fine.

2000W at 110V is something like 18A
the 10A is probably the 220V side.

that first one looks odd. 2.5A is in no way near 1875W, are you sure it's not 7.5A (if it's 7.5A that'd work too)

Comment: Yeah, it is written 2.5 A max. Pretty odd for a 1875W. Will try the 2000W then.Hope nothing breaks. Thanks!